# Cocos 2dx 4.x. Enable C++17 in Android Studio

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-android

I am trying to learn Cocos 2dx game engine. I generated a simple project with this command:

```
cocos new -l cpp -p com.testgame1 -d path_to_dir testgame1
```

Next, I try to build an android project. Everything is successful. Then I wrote a lot of code that uses C++ standard 14, 17. Example (file main.cpp):

```
void cocos_android_app_init(JNIEnv* env) {
    LOGD("cocos_android_app_init");
    std::string vec;
    std::transform(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), std::begin(vec), [](auto& elem)
                   {
                       return elem;
                   }
    );
    appDelegate.reset(new AppDelegate());
}
```

Here I using auto in lambda function (standart C++ 14).
I enable support for the standard in the usual way for Android Studio in build.gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.testgame1"
        minSdkVersion PROP_MIN_SDK_VERSION
        targetSdkVersion PROP_TARGET_SDK_VERSION
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                targets 'MyGame'
                cppFlags "-std=c++17 -frtti -fexceptions -fsigned-char"
                arguments "-DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=", "-DANDROID_STL=c++_static", "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang", "-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE"
            }
        }

        ndk {
            abiFilters = []
            abiFilters.addAll(PROP_APP_ABI.split(':').collect{it as String})
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't have any effect. On a clean project (no Cocos 2dx game engine) everything works flawlessly.
I am getting an error in Android Studio:

```
..\..\..\..\jni\hellocpp\main.cpp:42:72: error: 'auto' not allowed in lambda parameter
```

NDK: 21.4.7075529

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your game project folder, open up CMakeLists.txt, and add the following *after* the include(CocosBuildSet) statement:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
```

If you want to apply C++17 to the cocos2d engine code as well, then adding this may work:

```
set_target_properties(cocos2d PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD 17
    CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES
    CXX_EXTENSIONS NO
)
```

Source: [cocos2dx forum](https://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/cocos-2dx-4-x-enable-c-17-in-android-studio/56295)